# Displaying different messages via ajax at differing points during a PHP scripts execution

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins, upload

I am  using the following jquery file upload plugin to display progress bars when a user uploads mp3's.

http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

My server side script accepts the upload, converts the mp3 into a temporary wav file, generates a waveform image of the audio in png format then analyses the audio and stores the original mp3 filename, the png waveform, the analysed tempo and id3 information to the database.

All of this analysing and generating takes a few seconds to perform.  From around 5 seconds for an average 5-6mb mp3 file up to maybe a minute for a large 50mb podcast.

Obviously the progress bar finishes when the file itself has finished uploading, however the php script continues to run until the file analysis is complete.

What I would like to be able to do is display a message such as 'analysing your song' perhaps with an animated gif once the file is uploaded, and then once the php script has completed, display a final 'completed' message.

Can anyone give me any advice on how best to approach this within the confines of the jQuery plugin mentioned above and standard PHP.

I am reluctant to post my code here as it is such a huge script.  Therefore I will be content with more generic answers advising on the best approach to tackling this problem rather than detailed code modifications etc.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Super-duper simple solution: Maybe have the script write log messages about its progress to a file, and then poll that file from AJAX?

Script could delete the file when done, so when the AJAX eventually gets a 404, it could mean it's finished.

The name of the file could be same as audio file with '.log' appended to it or something.

Comment: Both yours and beerwin's seem like good simple solutions.  Thanks to the pair of you.  I'm going to leave the question open for a little while longer as I want to see a few more opinions as to the best approach to take.  Cheers!

Comment: @gordyr: Sounds like the right way to go! (waiting for several opinions that is :)

Answer (score 0):

Save the status messages into the session while processing the video,

Run timed ajax requests to retrieve the messages